# How to parse the geo location command output?

Tags: powershell, parsing, geolocation

I have the following function that will get your latitude and longitude.

```
function Get-GeoLocation{
    try {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Device #Required to access System.Device.Location namespace
    $GeoWatcher = New-Object System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher #Create the required object
    $GeoWatcher.Start() #Begin resolving current locaton

    while (($GeoWatcher.Status -ne 'Ready') -and ($GeoWatcher.Permission -ne 'Denied')) {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 #Wait for discovery.
    }  

    if ($GeoWatcher.Permission -eq 'Denied'){
        Write-Error 'Access Denied for Location Information'
    } else {
        $GeoWatcher.Position.Location | Select Latitude,Longitude #Select the relevent results.
    }
    }
    # Write Error is just for troubleshooting
    catch {Write-Error "No coordinates found" 
    return "No Coordinates found"
    -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    } 

}

$GL = Get-GeoLocation
```

It will output something similar to what you see below:

```
 Latitude  Longitude
 --------  ---------
55.500729 -55.059044
```

How can I parse this commmand in the most efficient way in order to load the latitude and longitude into their own variables?

Comment: If you're storing it in $GL, they can refer to it as $GL.Latitude and $GL.Longitude - how are you wanting it to be referred as?

Comment: Ditto. What is there to parse? You already receive an object with both properties you can use straigh away..

Comment: What you see is the formatted output of an object that has properties `Latitude` and `Longitude`. The formatted output is not intended for further processing, it is only for display purposes. As commenters already wrote, parsing it isn't even necessary because you can directly and efficiently access these properties using member access.